# Flowplayer Menu plugin issue

Tags: streaming, flowplayer, live-streaming

I am trying to implement bit rate selection like in flowplayer like in youtube. One option should be 'auto' and others manual. I am using a smil file to load my videos. Flowplayer documentation http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/flash/menu.html shows using the menu plugin. I cannot do it using that method since the url path is generated at run time. So I have use smil for menu creation and it works.I just mention the smil file name and the menu plugin loads the bit rates from the smil seamlessly. I am not exactly sure how this works though.

This is the code

```
clip: {
    url:"<?php echo getxml(); ?>",
    autoPlay: true,
    provider: 'rtmp',
    scaling:"fit",
    urlResolvers: [ 'smil', 'bwcheck','brselect' ],

    onStart: function() {

     }
},

plugins: {

    smil: {
        url: "flowplayer.smil/flowplayer.smil-3.2.8.swf"
    },

    bwcheck: {

        url: "flowplayer.bwcheck/flowplayer.bwcheck-3.2.11.swf",
        serverType: 'wowza',
        dynamic: true,
        dynamicBuffer:true,
        netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://itl.bc-s.cdn.bitgravity.com/cdn',
        checkOnStart: true,
        rememberBitrate: true,
        onStreamSwitchBegin: function(newItem, currentItem) {
               $f().getPlugin('content').setHtml("Will switch to: " + newItem.streamName +" from " + currentItem.streamName);
        },
        onStreamSwitch: function(newItem) {
               $f().getPlugin('content').setHtml("Switched to: " + newItem.streamName);
        }
    },

    menu: {
        url: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.menu-3.2.12.swf",
        items: [
           { label: " Auto",   enabled: true, index: 0,toggle:true , selected:true},

        ],
        onSelect: function(item) {


            if(item.index == 0){

                $f().getPlugin('bwcheck').enableDynamic(true);
                $f().getPlugin('content').setHtml("Auto Mode Slected : Best bit rate will be selected according to your bandwidth");
            }
            else{

                $f().getPlugin('bwcheck').enableDynamic(false);
                $f().getPlugin('content').setHtml("Manual bit rate selection activated");
            }
         }
    },


    brselect: {
        url: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.bitrateselect-3.2.13.swf",
        menu: true,
    },
```

As you can see from the code I placesd a single item like this

```
{ label: " Auto",   enabled: true, index: 0,toggle:true , selected:true},
```

By default auto mode is selected and I have to give a tick mark to the menu item 'Auto'. This was also achieved using the parameter 'selected'. But the problem is that the bit rate being played when the file starts playing in the auto mode is also selected and that too gets a tick mark like this.

http://tinypic.com/r/2nkt9fl/6

I need to disable that. The switching is happening and functionality is implemented but the user gets the wrong idea. There is a property by the name 'group' and I guess I will have to make all the items as a part of the group. A combination of the 'group' , 'selected' and 'toggle' property should be able do this but I cannot implement it.

Comment: I could trace out the values of item.label and item.label returns undefined for all values except "Auto". So I was thinking that if someone can show me how to change the value of 'selected' parameter of the item with label:"Auto" to false I can temporarily fix this problem..I can get onSelect event when other menu items and I can change the parameter there..